# MongoDB dbref in perl

Tags: perl, mongodb

Is there a way to do dbrefs using the Perl API?  Its not [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/DB+Ref) nor is it anywhere [here](http://api.mongodb.org/perl/index.html).

Here s a sample schema:

```
book: name, publisher,isdn,{author}
author : name,date of birth
```

I could just add a field to serve as the reference but wanted to do it with dbref instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no helpers for it, yet.  DBRefs are just normal hashes, though, so you can access/create them yourself.  They have the form:

```
 my $ref = {'$ref' => $collection_name, '$id' => $id};
```

See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/DB+Ref for more info.

Comment: Is this supposed to drastically increase insert time?

Comment: no, it will take the same amount of time as any other insert.

Answer (score 1):

It's also handled by MongoDBx::Class, but this is a fully fledged ORM so it may not fit your use case.

https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDBx::Class

Answer (score 0):

Its handle by MongoDBx::AutoDeref.

https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDBx::AutoDeref